# TensorFlow Segmentation Fault on M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, dataset

I am creating a data loading pipeline for image segmentation data. While after the data loads, it goes through an augmentation pipeline via `Albumentations`.

Here is the full code to the (parent) function: https://pastebin.com/0ZaeWnPz

Here is the source of the error:

```py
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_images, train_masks))
    val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((validation_images, validation_masks))
    if augment is None:
        return train_ds, val_ds

    @tf.function
    def augment_func(image, mask):
        data = {"image": image, "mask": mask}
        data_aug = UNIVERSAL_AUGMENTATION_FUNCTION(**data)
        img_aug = data_aug["image"]
        mask_aug = data_aug["mask"]
        aug_img = tf.cast(img_aug/255.0, tf.float32)
        aug_mask = tf.cast(mask_aug/255.0, tf.float32)
        return aug_img, aug_mask

    @tf.function
    def process_data(image, mask):
        aug_img, aug_mask = tf.numpy_function( # ERROR OCCURS HERE
            augment_func, inp=[image, mask], Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32])
        return aug_img, aug_mask

    @tf.function
    def set_shapes(image, mask, img_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3), msk_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)):
        image.set_shape(img_shape)
        mask.set_shape(msk_shape)
        return image, mask

    train_ds = train_ds.repeat(augmentation_expansion)
    train_ds = train_ds.map(partial(process_data), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).map(
        set_shapes, num_paralell_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

I have seen other SO question and GitHub issues, but it seems that their issue occurs in a different process and different/older version of TensorFlow.

**TensorFlow Version**: 2.9.2

**Python Version**: 3.8.13

**OS**: MacOS 12.5

**Mac Type**: M1 Pro (I feel it may have to do with this...)

I have tried adding `@tf.function` decorators as other posts have suggested but this still brings the same error. I have also tried using `tf.map_fn()` instead of `train_ds.map` but this did not work either. Can someone please help me and guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @AloneTogether https://pastebin.com/bTAUcMYS , but you will have to provide your own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`augment_func` returns **two** tensors, but by specifying `Tout=tf.float32`, you tell TF that the function returns only **one** tensor whose dtype is `tf.float32`. TF then treats `aug_img` and `aug_mask` as two tensors resulting from iterating over that single output tensor in the first dimension. Iterating over a tensor is supported only for Eager Execution, i.e., you can do

```
a, b = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 100))  # a.shape == b.shape == (100,)
```

but not

```
@tf.function
def split(x):
    a, b = x
    return a, b

split(tf.random.uniform((2,100)))  # Error: Operator not allowed in graph
```

because functions decorated with `tf.function` are executed using Graph Execution instead of Eager Execution.

So, simply specify `Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32]` to match the two returned tensors of `augment_func`.

On a not so related note, a map function must always return the transformed data, but your map function of

```
def set_shapes(image, mask, img_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3), msk_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)):
    image.set_shape(img_shape)
    mask.set_shape(msk_shape)
```

does not return anything. You need to return `image` and `mask` from it as well.

Comment: Leads to this error: https://pastebin.com/WT2bn6Db

Comment: I changed the question now to answer the question leading to the error trace above.

Comment: Does it happen in the first map or the second map? Could you try removing one of the two maps and call `next(iter(train_ds))` to identify the problematic one? I suspect it's because of the (imho unnecessary) `partial`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was at school. It seems that the error may be coming from the second map, (`set_shapes`). I split the map methods into two different variable assignments and put a `print(next(iter(train_ds))` in between. Here is the output of that:

`(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>)`

Comment: The shape is unknown which me be the reason for the error.

Comment: I think the reason is not because of `set_shape`, but because you did not return anything from that map function (you can see it complaining at `key: "Tout"`), so simply return `image` and `mask` from that function. I updated my answer.

Comment: I did this but now I am getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: It may be due to the fact that I am on an M1 Mac

Comment: Could you try using tf.ensure_shape or tf.reshape instead?

Comment: It gives still gives me a segmentation fault/bus error/abort but this time the model I am running starts training. The error happens instantaneously though.

Comment: I don't know how your data look like so at this point I'm pretty much out of guesses. You can use the `next(iter(train_ds))` method to check if the mappings produce your expected output.

Comment: They do not. Even after doing ensure shape, the shape of the data is still unknown. I think that this is what is causing the error.